# Save file in specific folder

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

In my Windows forms project, I am trying to save a file generated into a folder called "Invoice". I am able to save to the desktop, but how can it be saved to a subfolder?
I know this is very simple fix, but did some research but no luck with the solution.

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
    new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\" + ord + ".pdf",
    FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Amrit this should be a simple task, add the name of the folder you are wanting to save to the same way of how you were saving to the desktop, just replace that with the actual path `c:\somefilepath\Invoice`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the name of the folder in the same way that you add the name of the file:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Invoice\\" + ord + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
//                                                                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can also use `string.Format` to compose the path, like this:

```
var pathToPdf = string.Format(
    "{0}\\{1}\\{2}.pdf"
,   Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
,   "Invoice"
,   ord
);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pathToPdf, FileMode.Create));
```

Comment: Hmmm, I would have used `Path.Combine` instead of doing the concatenation manually.

Comment: @CodyGray With `Path.Combine` I'd have to use `ord+".pdf"` for the third argument, but I guess it's also OK.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the "\\" with "\Invoice\" + ord + ".pdf"

Answer (score 0):

If the folder does not exist then you need to create the folder and then write

Use [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx)

```
Directory.CreateDirectory Method (String)

Creates all directories and subdirectories as specified by path.
```

Example:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Users\SomeUser\My Documents\Foo\Bar\Baz\text1.txt";
Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    // ...
}
```

once done you can write into the folder like this

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + "\\Invoice\\" + ord + ".pdf", FileMode.Create));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use also [Save File Dialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfezx97z.aspx) and replace the first argument of FileStream with path that Save File Dialog returns.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like having everything in one line... this is what I'd do

```
string myFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "MyFolder");
string filePath = Path.Combine(myFolder, ord + ".pdf");
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
```